# EclipseLink produces duplicate entries in one-to-many relationship

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, one-to-many, many-to-one

I am using EclipseLink 2.4.1 and JPA 2.0. In my example I have the following class definitions:

```
@Entity
public class Shepard {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "shepard", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Sheep> sheeps;

    public void addSheep(Sheep sheep) {
        if (sheep != null) {
            if (sheeps == null) {
                sheeps = new ArrayList<>();
            }

            if (!sheeps.contains(sheep)) {
                sheeps.add(sheep);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Entity
public class Sheep {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="shepard_id")
    private Shepard shepard;

    public Sheep(Shepard shepard, String name) {
        this.shepard = shepard;
        this.name = name;

        shepard.addSheep(this);
    }
}
```

Now, when I write a Junit test and do the following. Note, that the Sheep constructor calls Shepard.addSheep(Sheep)!

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("data");
EnttyManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
Shepard shepard = new Shepard();

// I Persist Shepard
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(shepard);
em.getTransaction().commit();

// II Persist Tilda
Sheep tilda = new Sheep(shepard, "Tilda");
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(tilda);
em.getTransaction().commit();

// III Persist Martha via Shepard
Sheep martha = new Sheep(shepard, "Martha");
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.merge(shepard);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

And then do a named query for the Sheep's, I get a duplicate entry for "Tilda"!

This does not occur, when I code

```
em.persist(martha);
```

as the last entity manager access, instead.

Analyzing debug output, I can see that after **II** there is one Shepard object with [id=1] and one Sheep object with [id=1].
Before and after **III**, Shepard holds two references of Sheeps, before with [id=**1**] for Tilda and [id=null] for Martha.
After **III**, Shepard holds two references of Sheeps with [id=**2**] for Tilda and [id=3] for Martha.

From EclipseLink debug output, I can see that **III** issues **two** insert statements into the Sheep table.
In the database there end up **three** Sheep entries, with the id's as listed above.

Further I get the following error:

```
[EL Warning]: 2013-06-21 09:53:26.631--UnitOfWork(221387686)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Exception [EclipseLink-7251] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The attribute [id] of class [Sheep] is mapped to a primary key column in the database. Updates are not allowed.
```

Is this a bug of EclipseLink? Or what am I doing wrong, here?

Comment: Can you check what is in the collection after the merge call? Does a flush after tilda is persisted help?  What EclipseLink version are you using?

Comment: Edited question to answer your questions, Chris.

Answer (score 2):

In the Sheep class you have a "foreign key" to the Sheppard class which is not part of the primary key.

Try creating an Id class to use a compund key in the Sheep class.

```
@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name="shepard_id")
private Shepard shepard;
```

Comment: This does not work, neither for H2 nor MySQL, I get an org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException in both cases:
"Unique index or primary key violation", Error Code: 23505, on H2.
"Duplicate entry '2-1' for key 'PRIMARY'", Error Code: 1062, on MySQL.
Even, if I do a em.refresh(shepard) before em.merge(shepard)

Comment: The database needs to be updated too, removing the existing duplicate keys.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to call merge() as the shepard is already a managed object.  Merge is for detached/serialized objects, not managed objects.  If you have a cascade persist on Sheep, then you don't need to do anything, just call commit.

However, calling merge() should not be causing any issues, so that is very odd.  If you can recreate the issue in a test, please log a bug.  You may also want to try the 2.5 release, to see if it has been fixed.

My guess is that making the OneToMany EAGER might fix the issue.  Also if you create a new EntityManager for each transaction, then you would not have the issue (provided you call merge in both cases).